# Ideas for high school physics paper, including simulations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question, software

I have to write, with two friends, a simulation based physics paper at school.
The problem is, that will I am quite familiar with the concepts of calculus and algebra, my friends aren't.
So, we could find a good topic. The task is, to write a paper about a physical topic, with the use of a selfmade program. The development of the program shouldn't be a problem at all. we have a good programmer.
Any suggestions, for a topic that involves only pre-calculus math or only just some calculus?

Comment: If you've learned about momentum and elastic collisions already, simulating a very basic pool billiards game would maybe be an idea. Is this the kind of suggestions you're looking for?

Comment: This question appears to be an off-topic list question.

Comment: You could simulate what exo-planet transits along the line of site of Earth would look like for a local inhabitant of those systems. The geometry is basic enough (one circle occulting another one), the research is fresh, the data is on the internet and, if you want, you can throw in the relevance of Venus transits for astronomers a couple centuries ago.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found the establishment of the [Maxwell speed distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) from an initially random distribution interesting. Set up a bunch of particles with some initial speed distribution of your choosing, and as time goes on, collisions will tend to change the distribution to a well-known result. This is like billiards on drugs, though, and would involve significantly more time on your part.

Comment: I like the idea. See if you can do it for 2D - do you get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

As @Phonon suggested, a billiards game would be a good simulation.  Simulating orbital mechanics is another easy possibility - you only need sum of forces and kinematics.